# Web Intent from Youtube’s sharing menu with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-intent, youtube, share

I am trying to receive youtube link from youtube app. I tried “WebIntent” Capacitor plugin. I can see my app on Youtube’s sharing menu however I don’t know how to receive that link in my Ionic app?
Is it possible? Can you please help me?

Thanks…

Comment: can you share code snippet from you `app.component.ts` how you have handled this so far .. if not we will suggest you how you can do this

Comment: is it with cordova or with capacitors ?

Comment: I`m using Capacitor.

Comment: can you show a code sample